# Having an idea to a good question, where should i post it first?

Tags: discussion

i am developing a king-of-the-hill challenge. While i have a huge amount of ideas and a defined outline, the challenge is far from being completed.

I want this challenge to behave different to the normal KOTH-challenges that are out there. While the player (bot) has overall knowledge of the board, his minions (figures on the board) have not and are not directly controlled by the player.

While i have an idea that works well with this goal, i want to publish my draft and discuss changes in it with the codegolf community. But i feel like the draft is far away from being complete and does not fit into the sandbox. But defining the game rules on my own is something i feel is not the best idea, because the good challenges are closing loopholes etc. with the game design.

Also i seek advice on how to implement the controller and its interaction with the bots. (In terms of: "Would it be better to use I/O or interfaces or xyz")

Some options i have thought of:

- open a github repository and define the rules there for everyone to discuss
- open a chatroom here on stack exchange (perhaps with link to github)
- post a sandbox entry with my goals and a draft that is subject to change

What do you think would be my appropriate action in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this instance, I'd say post to the sandbox, with a link to a chat room, as well as the draft itself (edit the post as the draft updates). The chat room allows people to give interactive feedback without flooding the comment thread, and the sandbox entry allows people to vote on it. And editing the post allows people to change their votes.

For inter-process interactions, two common systems I know of are [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) and [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). Of course, feel free to discuss this and decide on something else, if neither of these suit your needs.

Comment: What is "The sandbox"?